# Fused Location Provider does not responding

Tags: android, location, google-play-services, android-fusedlocation, location-services

I have tested my app in `Moto G3(Android 6)`, `Vivo y19(Android 12)`, `Poco M2 pro(Android 11)`, `oppo A15(Android 10)`, `Nokia 2.1(Android 8)` everything works fine. **But when it comes to `POCO X3(Android 12, MIUI 13.0.1, android security: August 2022)` it is not working.**

**1.** If you are telling because of MIUI then how is it working on POCO M2?

**#** But after opening `google maps` app then accessing to current location in `Google maps`, my fusedLocation app is working fine. After removing the `Google maps` app from background again it is not working.

**My code :**

```
 LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(MainActivity.this)
                        .requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, new LocationCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onLocationResult(@NonNull LocationResult locationResult) {
                                super.onLocationResult(locationResult);
                                 //TODO
                                  }
                        }, Looper.getMainLooper());
```

**2.** Google maps app uses which library to access location? I know this question is weird, but if you know something about this you can tell.